# Does XMLHttpRequest strip credentials from url when specifying a port?

Tags: javascript, url, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

I have the following code:

```
var url = 'http://will:secret@localhost:5984/wells/_design/reading/_view/by_time'
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xmlHttp.open( 'GET', url, false )
xmlHttp.send( null )
console.log( xmlHttp.responseText )
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:5984/wells/_design/reading/_view/by_time 401 (Unauthorized)
```

When I omit the port from the url, I get the error:

```
GET http://will:secret@localhost/wells/_design/reading/_view/by_time 404 (Not Found)
```

Note that the credentials are removed from the first url and not the second. Is there any way for me to prevent them being removed?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell *why* they are stripped (maybe they actually arent, requesting the wrong ressource), but the usual way to specify basic auth credentials is passing them into the [`.open` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29):

```
var url = "http://localhost:5984/wells/_design/reading/_view/by_time";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( 'GET', url, false, "will", "secret" );
xmlHttp.send( null );
console.log( xmlHttp.responseText );
```

Comment: That does seem to be the right method of sending credentials, but the request is still failing with 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Do you get the credentials at your server? Maybe something there doesn't work. Or does it work if accessed directly?